# Laravel ORM Consultando relaciones

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, poo, eloquent

Tengo tres tablas y modelos relacionados entre sí y necesito consultar las propiedades cuyo `Environment.Name = 'Dormitorios'` y `PropertyEnvironment.Value = 2`:

1. `App\Property`:

   - id
   - address
   - etc

**Métodos:**

```
public function environments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\PropertyEnvironment');
}
```

---

2. `App\Environment`:

   - id
   - name

**Métodos:**

```
public function value()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\PropertyEnvironment');
}
```

---

3. `App\PropertyEnvironment`:

   - id
   - property_id
   - environment_id
   - value

**Métodos:**

```
public function environment()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Environment');
}

public function property()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Property');
}
```

---

Creo que la consulta correspondiente sería algo así:

```
SELECT *
FROM properties p
INNER JOIN property_environments pe ON pe.property_id = p.id
INNER JOIN environments env ON pe.environment_id = env.id
WHERE (env.name = 'Dormitorios')
AND (pe.value = 2);
```

¿Alguna idea? Agradezco de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No tengo como probarlo ahora pero creo que esto puede funcionar:

```
$properties = $properties->whereHas('environments', function($query)
{
    //En esta parte "$query" hace referencia a "PropertyEnvironment"
    $query->where('value', 2);
    $query->whereHas('environment', function($query) .
    {
        //En esta parte "$query" hace referencia a "Enviroment"
        $query->where('name', 'Dormitorios');
    });
});
```

**EDIT**

Le agregue unos comentarios para que se entienda un poco mejor para los que esten arrancando con Laravel y Eloquent

Comment: te "respondí" en la pregunta porque no me dejaba añadir multiínea

Comment: Puede ser que entonces hayas escrito mal tus relaciones entre modelos en la pregunta? porque ahi definis una relacion entre "Property " y "Environment", la llamaste "environments()"

Comment: tenés razón, la había escrito a modo de prueba y me olvidé de cambiarla por ese mismo motivo.

Comment: La marqué como correcta porque la idea está bien. Gracias.

Comment: Estaria bueno arreglar todas las relaciones y yo edito el codigo por el que vos terminaste utilizando asi puede ayudar a mas gente.

Comment: Tenés razón, ya la edité. Si la editas borro el comentario que hice con respecto a la edición.

Comment: ahora la edito, solo fijate que la relacion entre "Environment" y "PropertyEnvironment" la llamas "environments" pero en tu codigo veo que la llamaste "environment", puede ser?

Comment: es verdad, listo creo